# Self joining in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

In mongodb, using java I want to create the id's like if its the main object 1, 2, 3... child object then, 1.1,1.2,1.3... sub child object then 1.1.1,1.1.2,1.1.3.... is it possible to create like this? If so, then how to create it?

```
public class Main {
     private String id;
     private String mainName;
     private List<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {
     private String id;
     private String childName;
     private List<SubChild> subChilds;
}

public class SubChild {
    private String id;
    private String subChildName;
}
```

I want the mongodb object such that it should look like

```
{
 "id":"1",
 "mainName":"main",
 "childs":[{
   "id":"1.1",
   "childName":"child",
   "subChilds":[{
     "id":"1.1.1",
      "subChildName":"subChild"
    }]
 }]
}
```

Comment: id's are autogenerated

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Why do you need ids like that ? Can you explain the use case ?

Comment: Consider about the question paper, it should contain main question, inside that sub question, like it continuoes